# Что это за формат и как его преобразовать в текст?

Tags: rtf

предоставили старую базу данных в формате fdb. Я ее конвертировал в sql. Смотрю, а там данные вот в таком формате

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset204{\*\fname Times New Roman;}Times New Roman CYR;}{\f1\fnil Times New Roman;}}{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\lang1058\f0\fs24\'d4\'c3\'c4\'d1.\f1\par}
```

Никогда еще с таким не сталкивался и что то не могу нагуглить как это перевести в нормальный текст.

Подскажите, что это? В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Вы сами написали ответ в первой метке вопроса.

Comment: я понял, что это rtf, но как его преобразовать в обычный текст?

Comment: точнее, как вот это ```'d4'c3'c4'd1.``` перевести в текст